# How to create a underline in the text(one Letter) of QLabel in PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5

How to Create an underline in the text(selected Letter)  in PyQt5 QLabel ?.

My Expectation,
If I press, "Alt" key, then a single underline will show to that particular letter. and if I Press the "Cntrl" key then, the double underline will show that particular selected letter in a text.

For Example in my QLabel Text is "DashBoard", if I press "Alt", then a single underline will Show. In My case, I Select Letter D. ( single underline under the letter "D" )

In Another QLabel text is "Transaction", if I press the "Cntrl" key then  a double underline will show that particular selected letter , In my case I select "s", (double underline under s)

Comment: The first can partially be implemented; I say partially, because it could break functionality: what you're trying to do is normally called "mnemonics", it's already available as statically visible underscore under the letter preceded by "&" and refers to the keyboard shortcut connected to it (usually along with the Alt modifier). Depending on the style, the shortcut is already visible only when Alt is pressed. To enable this for QLabel, it must be set as [buddy](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlabel.html#setBuddy). The request about double underline is much harder, and I wouldn't suggest it anyway.

Comment: self.lbl_dashboard.setText('<font color="red"><font size = 4><u> D</u></font><font color="black">ash Board</font>')  ----- used this code for single underline. But I dont  know how to get double under line @musicamante

Comment: You cannot do it with standard Qt functions, there's no such thing as "double underline" in the text rendering engine. To achieve it, subclassing is required as *full* text rendering must be implemented, possibly using QTextDocument and QFontMetrics functions in order to get reliable results, otherwise the lines would be incorrectly aligned or look very ugly. That's not easy. If you *really* want to do that (but I wouldn't suggest it anyway), you need to do research and studying at least on the following topics: QPainter, QFontMetrics, QTextDocument, QTextBlock, QTextFormat, QTextCursor.